# How to Turn Off Lenovo Conservative mode using ubuntu

Tags: lenovo

I am unable to  Turn Off Lenovo Conservative mode using ubuntu

Comment: Could you explain in detail in your question    what is 'Lenovo Conservative Mode'  ?

Comment: Are you referring to Lenovo Conservation Mode?

Answer (score 3):

This may be because the Conservation Mode setting is enabled. Conservation Mode limits your battery charge to 55-60% to increase the duration for which you can get the maximum out of your battery. If you have a dual boot with Windows installed, boot into Windows, install Lenovo's Energy Manager, open Energy Manager, select the Settings tab, and disable Conservation Mode by toggling the slider from 1 to 0.

[image]

Comment: And why should it work in Ubuntu??

Comment: It's possible that Lenovo's own Energy Manager software for its laptops turns off Conservation Mode in the BIOS/UEFI firmware for all operating systems, not just for Windows.

Comment: hmm..Can you give more concreate proof of that? Normally, It should work in OS level

Comment: My concrete proof is if he tries it and it works, then it should also work for multiple Lenovo laptop models, otherwise I wasted my time posting this for nothing.

Comment: If that is true you should be able to change it in the BIOS.

Comment: @karel I'm not saying this won't work. Only wanted to see if there is any such discussion somewhere that can testify. Anyway I like softwares with nice gui. Hope OP can verify it :)

Answer (score 3):

Find the path for the conservation mode setting in `/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi` using `ls /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi`.

In my case, the path is `/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode`

You can then run (adjusting the path as needed)

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

`1` means conservation mode is active. Change it to `0` to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me and have Lenovo Legion:

```
sudo find / -type f -name conservation_mode
```

Then, as previously stated, change 1 to 0 (or other way around to turn it on)