# Lenovo - Conservative Mode (Ideapad 520)

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, ideapad

Is there any way to control conservative mode from ubuntu. I plan on removing windows but I like conservative mode.
I have found a lot of ways for thinkpad users but none for Ideapad 520.

Comment: What is "conservative mode"?

Comment: @Pilot6 it seems to be some way to conserve battery "health". Lenovo calls it Conservation Mode: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/conservation-mode-in-lenovo-ideapad/5d9fac36-8180-4c46-b15b-e65a7d47d8af

Comment: Some vendors have a setting in BIOS that charges a battery to 70-80% max to extend it's life. I don't think it's OS dependent.

Comment: It looks like the "conservative mode" management software (call it what you like) is windows specific. You have two options, leave windows so you can set it then boot into ubuntu, or use linux powersaving tools sa: `GNOME Power Statistics`

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/900306/how-to-turn-off-lenovo-conservative-mode-using-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its too late for you, but for others:
it works for me on my Lenovo IdeaPad C340-14IWL

use this command to **turn** it **on**:

```
echo  -n  "1" | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode > /dev/null
```

to **turn off** use same command but replace "1" to "0":

```
echo  -n  "0" | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode > /dev/null
```

or manually edit file .../conservation_mode

in this folder (...VPC2004:00/) i found "F toggle" file contains "0" or "1". changing it same above command can toggle function F keys (F1-F12).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ubuntu i would suggest a gnome extension that does exactly what the Lenovo vintage software does on windows. it is small with a 1 click install from Firefox. it also allows real time monitoring and works on my Lenovo Legion.

[link here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4129/charging-mode)

if you want a more manual approach here is how I used to do it.

::::::::: Conservative mode commands ::::::::

```
sudo su
```

then write your password.

reading the current status:

```
cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

0 is normal mode and 1 is conservation mode

enable Conservation mode:

```
echo 1  >  /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

disable conservation mode:

```
echo 0  > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```